# what is efficient way to access the data inside the function in my case?

Tags: php

I have a php page on which I get some data like this

```
$data = $_GET["data"];
```

$data is used on the page and inside a function i.e.

```
function myfunction() {
   some code here
}
```

this function is called many times on this page if needed

my question is what is efficient way to access the data inside the function?

1.

```
function myfunction() {
   $data = $_GET["data"];
}
```

or
2.

```
function myfunction() {
   global $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most efficient way it to use $_GET["data"] directly where needed without declaring and assigning it to a new variable

e.g

```
//do your isset() checks here, not within the function

function myfunction(){
    if($_GET['data']==="whatever"){ //note that === checks is faster than ==, if you are sure of the type being checked
        //do something
    }
}
```